# Who is this blue headed droid in "A New Hope"?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, droids

Who is this blue-headed droid on Tatooine? It can be seen in *A New Hope* next to the protocol droid CZ-1.

[image: The droid in question (blue head with control panel in a sideways diamond shape atop a cylindrical body with arms out the side running on tracks, moves down the street alongside the protocol droid CZ-1]

Comment: That was “Not the droid they’re looking for”.

Comment: Another protocol droid with leaky knees!

Answer (score 21):

This is [WED-9-M1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/WED-9-M1).

He was first identified in the [Star Wars collectible card game](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/cardguide/images/6/6f/Wed9m1banthadroid.gif/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340?cb=20141209212850) (as a *"WED-9-M1 'Bantha' Droid"*) and officially canonised in the video below.

[image]

You might want to note that this is a custom built robot, based on the standard Treadwell models.

Comment: What the heck kind of task does a "bantha droid" do? Milk banthas? Herd banthas? Track banthas?

Comment: @Lexible - The blurb on the [card](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/cardguide/images/6/6f/Wed9m1banthadroid.gif/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340?cb=20141209212850) says that it's nicknamed "bantha" for its slow and stubborn nature

Comment: Not a halfway bad card, either, if I remember the gameplay correctly.

Comment: Colourful nicknames aside, what purpose was it assembled for?

Comment: @Nu'Daq - The blurb on the [card](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/cardguide/images/6/6f/Wed9m1banthadroid.gif/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340?cb=20141209212850) says that it's owned by the people who operate Docking Bay 94. It's identified as a "maintenance droid", taking care of ships and droids.